# something better than httrack to download files?

Tags: download, httrack, file-download

I am trying to download documents (pdf, tiff, images) from webpages that have javascript and frames in them. example: http://127.0.0.1/web/guest/en/websys/webArch/mainFrame.cgi

'httrack --get-files' didn't download any, are there other ways you may think of? another program? will I have to write that program myself?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that URL ends with "cgi", I would guess that this is running a CGI script on the server -- meaning that it's probably expecting other data. There are a couple of options about where it could be getting this data

First, this other data could come from your logged in session. Look at the docs for wget for the `--load-cookies` option to specify that it should use the cookie file from your browser (the instructions in my computer are for old browser cookie file formats).

The other option is that it's expecting POST data from your browser. You'll need to figure out what the form variables and values are and pass those using wget's `--post-data` or `--post-file` options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Doug, but I'm not sure I understand what needs to be done with post-data, could you give me an example?

Comment: You would need to use a tool to examine the data sent when you click on the link in your browser -- Fiddler2 is a good option if you're on Windows. Once you have that you'll need to encode it in a way to pass as POST data -- there's an example in the wikipedia page about POST requests http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)